# Sql date comparison in where clause is not working as expected

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, date-comparison

I'm facing a strange mysql behavior...

If I want to return the rows from "MyTable" with a date lower than date-10 seconds ago or a future date 
*I also store future date because in my real program, I "launch" some queries with delay and date is actually the last query date...i.e.: a kind of queue...*:

```
SELECT (NOW() - date) AS new_delay, id 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE (NOW() - date < 10) 
ORDER BY new_delay DESC;
```

This one does not work as expected: **It returns all the entries**:

EDIT: here is the result:

[image]

However, this one is working just fine:

```
SELECT (NOW() - date) AS new_delay, id 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE (NOW() < date + 10) 
ORDER BY new_delay DESC;
```

---

DB example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MyTable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


INSERT INTO `MyTable` (`id`, `date`) VALUES
(1, (NOW())),
(2, (NOW()-10)),
(3, (NOW()+100));
```

---

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As proposed by @Gordon in the his answer, I can use the date_sub / date_add functions...

I can correct the where clause to be  :

```
WHERE NOW() < date_add(ServerRequests.date, interval 10 second)
```

OR

```
WHERE date > date_sub(now(), interval 10 second)
```

OR as proposed in my initial post:

```
WHERE (NOW() < date + 10)
```

But I still don't see why I cannot use the sub operation...So if anyone can give me a reason, I would be happy to understand...

Answer (score 0):

use mysql `DATEDIFF`

```
select DATEDIFF(curdate(),date) as new_delay, id from MyTable 
where date >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 10 day)
ORDER BY new_delay DESC;
```

> DATEDIFF() function returns the time between two dates

Comment: Thanks, but I need to compare seconds, not days... In doc: "DATEDIFF() returns expr1 − expr2 expressed as a value in days from one date to the other. "

Comment: use **TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,date, curdate())** @Bast

Answer (score 0):

Don't do the comparisons like that.  In a numeric context `now()` end up being converted to an integer -- and in an arcane format.  Instead, use  `DATEDIFF()` or just regular comparisons.  For instance, if you want the difference in days:

```
SELECT datediff(curdate(), date) as new_delay, id
FROM MyTable
WHERE date >= date_sub(now(), interval 10 day) 
ORDER BY new_delay DESC;
```